# vbscript for each loop to for loop

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript

Hi I have written a program in VBScript, now I want to replace `For Each` loop with a `For` loop.

```vb
For Each node In objMSXML.selectNodes(sXPath)                   
    Set li = document.createElement("li")
    li.innerText = i & " " & node.text
    ul.appendChild li
    i = i +1
Next
```

I have not been able to figure it out as I also need to know the number of nodes returned from Xpath.

Comment: Why do you want to use a `For` instead of a `For Each`? If it's because you want to workout the number of nodes you don't need to the [`IXMLDOMNodeList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms767664(v=vs.85).aspx) is a collection so just use the [`length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757044(v=vs.85).aspx) property like this `NumOfNodes = objMSXML.selectNodes(sXPath).length` to retrieve the number of nodes.

Comment: This is a duplicate anyway - [XPath count in VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/594667/692942) - See [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node list returned by .SelectNodes() is a collection with a .length property that can be traversed using a zero-based integer index:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim oFS    : Set oFS  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim sFSpec : sFSpec   = oFS.GetAbsolutePathName("..\data\33921005.xml")
Dim oXML   : Set oXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
oXML.load sFSpec
If 0 = oXML.parseError Then
   Dim ndlName : Set ndlName = oXML.selectNodes("/Envelope/Body/Request/individual/hasName/*")
   Dim ndName
   For Each ndName In ndlName
       WScript.Echo ndName.tagName
   Next
   Dim iNd
   For iNd = 0 To ndlName.length - 1
       WScript.Echo iNd, ndlName(iNd).tagName
   Next
Else
   WScript.Echo oXML.parseError.reason
End If
```

output:

```
cscript 36053711.vbs
firstName
lastName
0 firstName
1 lastName
```

Comment: We [know](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36053711/vbscript-for-each-loop-to-for-loop#comment59755266_36053711).

Comment: What's with `If 0 = oXML.parseError Then` maybe it's just me but doing like that is triggering my [OCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder), is there some benefit to that?

Answer (score 3):

*Following on from my [initial comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36053711/vbscript-for-each-loop-to-for-loop/36057200#comment59755266_36053711).*

The `selectNodes()` method returns a [`IXMLDOMNodeList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms767664(v=vs.85).aspx) object which is a [NodeList](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-536297177) collection.

As with any collection it contains members common to collection objects

> **Properties**
>
> - [`length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757044(v=vs.85).aspx) - *Number of Nodes in the collection*
>
> **Methods**
>
> - [`item`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757028(v=vs.85).aspx) - *Access to individual Nodes within the collection*
>
> <sub>For full list of member properties and methods see
>   [IXMLDOMNodeList
>   Members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms767664(v=vs.85).aspx)</sub>

There should be no logical reason why you need to change your `For Each` to a `For` loop as you can just use the `length` property to retrieve the number of Nodes in the collection.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim node, nodes, li, i, sXPath, NumberOfNodes
Set nodes = objMSXML.selectNodes(sXPath)
'Retrieve number of Nodes
NumberOfNodes = nodes.length
For Each node In nodes                   
    Set li = document.createElement("li")
    li.innerText = i & " " & node.text
    ul.appendChild li
    i = i +1
Next
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [Document Object Model (Core) Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html)
- [MSDN - IXMLDOMNodeList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757073(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: What was the reason for un-accepting? Does the solution not work is there a problem with the code?